# Separation of variables and heat

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation:$$u_t-ku_{xx}-\alpha u=0, x>0, x<2\pi , t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=u(2\pi,t), t\geq 0,$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(2\pi,t), t\geq 0,$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
$f$ is a smooth periodic function and $k>0$ and \alph is a real number.
I want to solve this equation using separations.
I did this:
Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ them we have:$$u_t=XT^\prime$$
$$u_{xx}= X^{\prime\prime}T$$.
Then plugging these into the original equation we conclude:
$$XT^\prime-kX^{\prime\prime}T-\alpha XT=0$$
Hence:
$$\frac{T^\prime}{T} = \frac{kX^{\prime\prime}+\alpha X}{X}= - \lambda$$
Therefore:
$$T^\prime + \lambda T =0$$ $$and$$  $$X^{\prime\prime} + (\frac{\alpha + \lambda}{k}) X =0$$
Can anyone please help me how can I proceed from here?
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you proceed from here? What have you learned that would help you solve the problem?

Comment: @Mattos When I want to find a solution for $X(x)$ I can’t find a nontrivial solution. I always find $X(x)=0$.

Comment: How did you arrive at $X(x)=0$? Can you edit your question to show that?

Comment: @Dylan  I put $$ \frac{T^\prime}{T}=-\lambda$$ and ended up finding : for $$  \frac{\alpha + \lambda}{k} >0 $$ $$ X(x)= C_1\cos(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha + \lambda}{k}}x)+ C_2\sin(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha + \lambda}{k}}x)$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122793/separation-of-variables-for-a-periodic-problem) before. Consider editing it instead of asking a new one.

Starting from here

$$ XT' -kX''T - \alpha XT = 0 $$

Divide through by $XT$ to get

$$ \frac{T'}{T} - k\frac{X''}{X} = \alpha $$

Let $\frac{X''}{X} = -\lambda$ then

\begin{cases} X'' + \lambda X = 0 \\ T' + (k\lambda-\alpha)T = 0 \end{cases}

We want the solution to be $2\pi$-periodic in $X$, so $\lambda = n^2$ and the general solution is

$$ u(x,t) = A_0e^{\alpha t} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [A_n\cos(nx) + B_n\sin(nx)]e^{-(kn^2-\alpha)t} $$